# Rollup: dealing with dependencies that are typescript files. Getting Error: Unexpected token

Tags: typescript, rollup, rollupjs

Here is a [github repo](https://github.com/mike-hogan/rollup-ts-deps) that reproduces this problem.

I have this package.json:

```
{
  "name": "rollup-ts-deps",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Mike Hogan",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.2.0",
    "rollup": "^2.41.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@http4t/core": "0.0.121"
  }
}
```

and this rollup.config.js

```
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';

export default {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: {
        file: 'lib/index.js',
        format: 'cjs'
    },
    plugins: [
        typescript()
    ]
};
```

and src/index.ts contains this:

```
import {post} from "@http4t/core/requests";

console.log(post)
```

When I run `npx rollup -c` I get:

```
[!] Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
node_modules/@http4t/core/requests.ts (5:30)
3: import {Authority, Uri, UriLike} from "./uri";
4: 
5: export function request(method: Method, uri: UriLike, body?: HttpBody, ...headers: Header[]): HttpRequest {
```

How do I configure rollup to deal with dependencies that are Typescript files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This commit](https://github.com/mike-hogan/rollup-ts-deps/commit/9f0a33d6dd5a28d4b8947d165ea82166c1a87510) demonstrates a fix for the issue.

In summary, I added the following `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "ES2020",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/esm",
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": [
    "./src",
    "node_modules/@http4t"
  ]
}
```

The important piece is to include `node_modules/@http4t` as a source directory.

`frederikhors` comments on [this issue](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/issues/842) was the telling contribution.

Comment: is adding whole node_modules/ wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours trying to find a fix for this, and it turned out to be a simple plugin order issue.

You need to use [@rollup/plugin-node-resolve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-node-resolve) to bring in third-party modules from node_modules. I was already doing that, but I was using the TypeScript plugin first. Swapping the order resolved the issue for me:

```js
// rollup.config.js
import nodeResolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';

export default {
    // ...
    plugins: [
        nodeResolve(), // must come before the typescript plugin!
        typescript(),
    ]
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work